# What does "Maximum Input Current" in a data sheet mean?

Tags: current, datasheet

For example, in the datasheet of ATS030A0X3-SRPHZ, what does the maximum input current mean? Does it mean...

1) This is how much you are allowed to feed into the voltage translator (presumably using a current source) without breaking it?

OR

2) This is how much current the voltage translator will ever draw, so go ahead and design your circuit allocating this much current to this component?

Thanks

Comment: I'd gather it's the max current you're allowed to draw from the input voltage source to achieve the max 30A output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example given, it's the maximum current the device will draw when:

> \$V_{IN} = V_{IN, min} \$
>   \$V_{O} = V_{O,set}\$
>   \$I_{O} =I_{O,max}\$

For the most part, specific test conditions are given for how maximums and minimums were measured. Holding the outputs steady, if you were to increase the input voltage, the input current would drop. So, assuming you aren't going to violate any of the other inputs or outputs, the current should not increase above the specified value.

This most closely matches option two that you've given. You should design to actively maintain the voltage specifications and the current will behave accordingly.